# Retrieve the exported Xliff Files in ektron workarea by passing content id using API

Tags: ektron, xliff

I need to get the exported Xliff files from the ektron workarea using Content ID. Is there any API to get the list of Xliff Files by passing content Id in ektron

Please anyone help me in this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to get the XLIFF history by using Content ID,but you can make use of corresponding JOB Id to get this information.Go through Localization API to get more info on this.